# SP 2013 Search does not uniquely index friendly URLs that point to the same physical page

Tags: 2013, search, crawling, managed-navigation

I have an on-premise SP 2013 farm that I will be using to host a Internet (public-facing/anonymous) site. I'm using managed navigation with term-driven pages. Three of my navigation links point to one physical page (FAQ.aspx). On that page I have a single content query webpart pointed at a custom list and I have it's "Filter by page navigation term" property checked. The idea here is that I will see a different set of content on the page depending on the navigation item I clicked. For instance if I navigate to /holidays I will see a list of holidays and if I navigate to /hours I will see a list of operating hours. Same physical page but different content. I have setup my search service with a content source of type "Web Site" and pointed it at the URL of my SP site. So I am crawling the site as a web site not as a SharePoint site. I am interested in indexing the unique content of each friendly url.

However, when I search for a word such as Thanksgiving which only appears on on my /holidays page, I get three search results - for each of my friendly urls that point to my FAQ.aspx page.

What appears to be happening is that SharePoint knows that my friendly urls all point to the same FAQ.aspx page so it just goes and indexes that page. If you navigation to FAQ.aspx (no friendly url) the CQWP will not have a nav term to filter by so it shows all items from my list and search then indexes FAQ.aspx will all that list content. SharePoint does not appear to be crawling the pages AS friendly urls. If it were I should only see one search result for my /holidays page when I search for Thanksgiving.

This one has me stumped. Is it even possible to do what I am trying to do? Can SharePoint crawl a friendly url as the friendly url? Any ideas, suggestions or wild guesses are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the "Hide physical URLs from search" checkbox on the publishing pages? Check this: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/wcm-tip-20-hide-physical-urls-search-working-managed-navigation/

Comment: Yes, the that box is checked and the search results are returning friendly urls. The issue is that the friendly urls are not indexed as separate pages.

Answer (score 0):

Could be it is "trimming" what it sees as "near duplicates" ...Use Fiddler trace and look at HTTP - response raw ... Look for something like Trim or collapseSpecification":"DocumentSignature:1